# Django models.DateTimeField and Postgres int

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My class Model has following timestamp:

```
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

It works fine with SQLLite, but changing to Postgres I am getting error:

> column "timestamp" is of type integer but expression is of type
>   timestamp with time zone

I want to keep my model with DateTimeField but how to convert this type required by Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#datefield

Comment: This does not work. Type remain the same and getting error. More over will need to modify value of timestamp as this will be provided from barcode readers.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping database in SQL, removing all migrations sort problem. There must be something left from SQLLite that generated error.